# React Native Axios post request does not work on localhost

Tags: symfony, react-native, axios

I got a big situation here.
I'm using Mobx and axios, i'm trying to post a request with axios on localhost, who calls my api made with Symfony.

Here's the code :

@action
  async inscriptionAxios() {

```
const query = {
  "nom": "Johan11",
  "prenom": "Louap11",
  "email": "jlouap111@email.fr",
  "dateNaissance": "1996-12-11",
  "login": "Leiko9849",
  "password": "mdpLeiko118198"
};

const header =  {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}

console.log('query', query, header)

await axios
  .post('http://localhost:8000/register', query, header)
  .then(response => {
      console.log('response _inscriptionAxios', response)

    // extendObservable(this._reservation, response.data)
    this._inscription = Object.assign({}, response.data)
  }) 
  .catch ((err) => {
    console.log('Erreur : ' + err)
  })
```

}

But I got this error response : "Error: Network Error"
And error.response "undifined"

I tried to change "localhost" to my ip adress and it did not work.
I tried to change "localhost" to 127.0.0.1 and it did not work to.

Can I make it work ??

Thanks boys

Comment: I think this isn't a react native/ axios issue, if you are getting Network Error as response your server is either not running or you are using the wrong ip

Comment: use ip address like `127.0.0.1` or `192.168.X.X`

Comment: Is anything running locally on port 8000 that can respond?

Comment: @Kape the server is running well, i can test it with Postman and it works

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev already tried but not working :(

Comment: @DrewReese yes It works with postman

Comment: use if you are using `chrome` plugin `CORS`

Comment: I'm using a genymotion emulator.

Answer (score 1):

- First, try with these ip addresses **10.0.2.2** or **10.0.3.2** if you are using android emulator(AVD) or genymotion emulator.
- If the first approach is failed, try this command below at your terminal if your local server itself is working fine with postman.

```
adb reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8000
```

I had a similar issue before that happened with RN Android app.

I have had setup golang server locally but could not sent a request from my android test device. What I have found is something that related to port of local RN package server. Maybe you also need to forward your port of the localhost.